# empty list and empty CSV file

Tags: python, dataframe, twitter, append, tweepy

I am trying to scrape twitter, below is my code and my problem is that it is returning an empty list (not appending data) accordingly, it creates a csv file that only has the heeaders !!

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

search_words = ["#covid19", "easter", "stockholm"]
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

tweets = []


# Open/create a file to append data to
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

#Use csv writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                            q = search_words,
                            since = "2019-03-30",
                            until = "2020-04-30",
                            lang = "en").items(100):


    try: 
        data = [tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.text, tweet.user._json['screen_name'], tweet.user._json['name'], tweet.user._json['created_at'], tweet.entities['urls']]
        data = tuple(data)
        tweets.append(data)

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        continue

    except StopIteration:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns = ['created_at','tweet_id', 'tweet_text', 'screen_name', 'name', 'account_creation_date', 'urls'])

df.to_csv(path_or_buf = 'tweets.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this code? Please reduce to a [mre].

Comment: The legacy standard search API that tweepy uses only supports the past 7 days of Tweets, so cannot retrieve Tweets between March 2019 and April 2020. That's almost certainly why your `tweet` variable ends up being empty, and so does your resulting Dataframe and CSV file. You would need to use the premium full-archive search API to find Tweets in that time period.